# How to deprecate use of SQL Database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to disable Rails from trying to obtain a connection to my Postgres database because my application no longer should rely on this database.

I'm currently in a transition from using Postgres to using a NoSQL database such as Mongo. I have most of the code migrated but I'm currently running a shadow write to Postgres for backwards compatibility reasons.

Is it sufficient  to remove the ActiveRecord middlewares and shadow write code so that if Postgres were to fail or the connection pool stalled the Rails application would experience no timeout or downtime?

Comment: One way to shake out all your bugs is to kill your Postgres instance and watch all your tests fail. If you don't have tests, that's a big problem you should work to resolve.

Comment: I have some tests for these scenarios, and also 
I have a implemented a try catch block around the middleware obtaining a connection such that it will proceede if the postgres is shut off. 

What im having trouble is preventing issues such as a full connection pool and requests stalling for 10+ seconds.

Comment: There's no singular answer for this sort of thing. It's highly situational.

Comment: So removing the ActiveRecord::ConnectionManagement isn't enough to cease connections to postgres?

Comment: You're talking about two different things: Removing Postgres completely vs. having it in place but dealing with dead connections. If you don't want to connect to Postgres, trash your `config/database.yml` so it has no way to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `ActiveRecord` from your application, do the following:

In `config/application.rb`, change this:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

To this:

```
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

In `environments/development.rb`, remove this line, and any others that reference `config.active_record` that you may have added:

```
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
```

In `environments/production.rb` remove this line and any others that reference `config.active_record` that you may have added:

```
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

If you have a file at `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`, remove the following line from it:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

Finally, remove any references to `ActiveRecord`, such as in any models, migrations, or `schema.rb`, if still present. It's probably best to nuke your `db` folder entirely.

Note: If you're no longer using any of `ActiveModel` you can also remove it from the requires in `application.rb`.

---

To remove support and functionality for connecting to your Postgres database, remove the file `config/database.yml` and remove the `gem 'pg'` declaration from your Gemfile (then run `bundle install`).